# How do you solve "Syntax error in INSERT statement"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb, ole, oledbexception

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form2
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Dimph\OneDrive\Desktop\Richfield BSC IT --- 1st year\Second Semester\Programming 512\Assignment\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Database2.accdb")

    Private Sub btnUplaodImage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim Filename As String()
        Filename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Split("\c")
        'Filename.CopyTo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "Upload\" + Filename(Filename.Length - 1))
        MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBrowserImage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox5.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim Gender As Boolean
        If rdFemale.Checked = True Then
            Gender = True
        ElseIf rdMale.Checked Then
            Gender = False
        End If

        If txtLastName.Text = Nothing Or txtName.Text = Nothing Or txtPassword.Text = Nothing Or txtUsename.Text = Nothing Or rdFemale.Checked = Nothing Or rdMale.Checked = Nothing Or DateTimePicker1.Value = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter Input Field !", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into [Sign_Up] ([Name], Lastname,Date of birth, Gender,[Password],UserName)Values (@Name, @LastName, @Date of birth, @Gender, @[Password], @Username", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date of birth", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Gender
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsename.Text

            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            connection.Close()
            MsgBox("Account creation suceed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Change 'Date of birth' to '[Date of birth]' and possibly update the corresponding parameter to something without spaces, like '@DateOfBirth'.

Comment: And use cmd.ExecuteNonquery  - not a reader.

Comment: Also, don't store passwords as plain text.

Comment: Avoid spaces and punctuation/special characters in naming convention (underscore is only exception) as well as reserved words as names - Name is a reserved word.